# Lag and Lead partition by and counts

Tags: sql-server

Here is my sample data:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (id integer, indiv varchar(20), status varchar(20), date date)
INSERT @a VALUES
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/08'),
('649598','Walker','Download','2017/09/09'),
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/10'),
('649598','Kruger','Download','2017/09/11'),
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/12'),
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/17'),
('649598','Kruger','Download','2017/09/18'),
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/10/01'),
('649598','Hazle','Download','2017/11/02'),
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/11/05'),
('649598','Jones','Download','2017/11/06'),
('649598','System','Reassign','2017/12/01'),
('649598','Don','Download','2017/12/02'),
('506013','Topps','Download','2017/11/06'),
('506013','System','Reassign','2017/12/01'),
('506013','Goss','Download','2017/12/02');
```

From an earlier post, I did not include id's and got results for return the previous and next indiv on a status row of Reassign.
How do I break by ID?
Ultimately, I want to (1) count the times an ID has a status of reassign and (2) count the times an indiv had it reassigned to and from.

For example, ID 649598 Kruger had it reassigned to him twice, reassigned from him twice.

```
select * 
     , (select top 1 l.indiv from @a l where l.status <> 'Reassign' and l.date < a.date order by l.date desc) as lag
     , (select top 1 l.indiv from @a l where l.status <> 'Reassign' and l.date > a.date order by l.date asc)  as lead
from @a a 
where a.status  = 'Reassign' 
union all 
select a.*, null, null 
from @a a
where a.status <> 'Reassign' 
order by id, date




SELECT *
       ,Prev = CASE WHEN a.status <> 'Download' THEN
                  (SELECT TOP 1 indiv FROM @a WHERE [date] < a.[date] AND status <> 'Reassign' ORDER BY [date] DESC) END
       ,Next = CASE WHEN a.status <> 'Download' THEN
                  (SELECT TOP 1 indiv FROM @a WHERE [date] > a.[date] AND status <> 'Reassign' ORDER BY [date]) END
FROM @a a
```

Comment: Show your expected output please

Answer (score 0):

is this useful.?

```
    DECLARE @a TABLE (id integer, indiv varchar(20), status varchar(20), date date)
    INSERT @a VALUES
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/08'),
    ('649598','Walker','Download','2017/09/09'),
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/10'),
    ('649598','Kruger','Download','2017/09/11'),
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/12'),
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/09/17'),
    ('649598','Kruger','Download','2017/09/18'),
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/10/01'),
    ('649598','Hazle','Download','2017/11/02'),
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/11/05'),
    ('649598','Jones','Download','2017/11/06'),
    ('649598','System','Reassign','2017/12/01'),
    ('649598','Don','Download','2017/12/02'),
    ('506013','Topps','Download','2017/11/06'),
    ('506013','System','Reassign','2017/12/01'),
    ('506013','Goss','Download','2017/12/02');

    SELECT * ,
    LEAD(indiv) OVER(partition by id order by date ) as ReassignedTo,
    LAG(indiv) OVER(partition by id order by date ) as ReassignedFROM
    into #tmpReassign
    FROM @a
    order by id desc,date


    select id,reassignedTo,Count(*) ReassignedToCount ,
    Count(*) ReassignedFROMCount
    from #tmpReassign 
    where status='Reassign'
    Group by id,reassignedTo


    drop table #tmpReassign
```